# Using oninput function with php?

Tags: php, html, button

As far as I've seen, the `oninput` funciton in HTML is always used with Javascript. Is it possible to add PHP into it?

```
<input name="boxNo" type="number" value="1" oninput="<?php $intro = $intro . "boxNo.value"?>"/>
```

If it is possible, how should I structure my code?

Comment: You can use PHP to generate the JavaScript.

Comment: the answer is simply no ... PHP = Server | HTML= client ... what you want is maybe some AJAX call using JS to call server and run some PHP and then get back to JS with a result

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't call php directly from html as shown in your example.
But you can use AJAX to do it, using JS, jQuery and PHP script placed on your server.

For example:

JavaScript:

```
    $('input[name=boxNo]').input(function(){
        var inputObject = $(this);
        var value = inputObject.val();
        $.post('/yourfileOnServer.php', {value: value}, function(data){
            //in the variable data you've already got your info from the php
            inputObject.val(data); //inserting data to the value of your input
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
   if(!isset($_POST['value'] || empty($_POST['value'])){
      exit; //Avoiding security problems
   }
   $value = $_POST['value']; //In this variable you store your value, entered to the input
   // DO something with this value
   echo $value; //and print it  (return to the JS)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Personally, I would do `if(isset($_POST['value'])){ $value = $_POST['value']; } else { exit; }` --- `isset()` could also be `!empty()`. In either case though, there should be an `else { $value = $_POST['value']; }` that way the value won't throw a possible undefined index notice.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, if you use exit;, there will no undefined index notice because of stopping script.